# extraprops override existing props

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

i am trying to add z-index to all existing blocks, so i use filters. but in the save aspect there is an issue: lets say i use a group block, and inside it a spacer block, and so on. the style props of the spacer (and other blocks) are override by my new extraprops. now, i use Object.assign, which means it should add the new value to the existing props and not override it, but it does.

this is my function:

```
const positionzStyles = (extraProps, blockType, attributes) => {
const { gutrszIndex } = attributes;


 const gutrsstyles = {};

if (typeof gutrszIndex !== 'undefined' && gutrszIndex) {
//Object.assign({},extraProps, { style: {zIndex: gutrszIndex} });
gutrsstyles['z-index'] = gutrszIndex;
}


 Object.assign(extraProps, { style: gutrsstyles });


//console.log('save: ', extraProps);

return extraProps;


}

 wp.hooks.addFilter(
 'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps',
 'gutrs/position-z-styles',
  positionzStyles
 );
```

any idea what i'm missing here? is there another way, to add inline styles for existing blocks?

best regards